# File reader encapsulation in a table reader

Tags: c#

I have a file reader object that i need to read a file with tables in it. I want to create an object called Table to hold the row and column data from the read file. The trouble is, to read the whole page, i need to have a list of tables (there are more than one in the file). WHat is the best structure of my classes so that i am not exposing the data reader too much and passing it around too much?

My current line of thinking is this:

1. Create a class that instantiates a list of tables and pass this class the reader.
2. Run the reader and for each new table found, instantiate a new table object and pass along the reference to the reader so it can get row/column info.

Is this the best way to do this kind of task? Or is there a more efficient design to restrict the reader being passed too much? I have to use the `using` statement and it just doesnt feel right to use it in this nested design

Thanks

Comment: Does the table structure change at all or is it fixed?  Could also provide a small sample of the input?

Comment: the number of rows and columns differ between each table. the info is a bit sensitive so i cant provide a sample. but just think of it as tables in a word doc with headers/columns/rows

Comment: Is the information at least delimited in the same fashion?  Comma/pipe/tilde separated or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially use the already available `DataTable`.  There is a little bit of overhead in using them, but it *sounds* like it would be something easy to work with.

You did say that the tables contain different structures.  Is there anything in the file that identifies the table changing?  This could make it more difficult if there are many 'tables' in the same file.

You can simply use a collection of type `DataTable` if you want to have a list of them around.  I suppose you could create your own class for this if your design warrants that.

```
List<DataTable> tables = new List<DataTable>();
```

and a sample method of how it may be used:

```
private IList<DataTable> GetTables()
{
    IList<DataTable> tables = new List<DataTable>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pathAndFile))
    {
        //pseudo-code below
        //Iterate through tables in the file: foreach(DiscoveredTable table in file)
        //parse from csv: table = GetTableFromCsv(table.DataFromTheFile);
        //add to tables collection: tables.Add(table);
    }

    return tables;
}
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) is a link to a CSV parser if you are interested in going that route, since you said it is comma-separated.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would go with the idea of encapsulating the Table collection in your own class that controls the reader.  I would also not allow public instantiation of either object if hiding those details is a concern.  Something like this.

```
public class TableCollection : List<Table>
{
   private TableCollection() { }

   public static TableCollection FromFile(string filePath)
   {
       using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
       {
           //populate all tables here before disposing
       }
   }
}

public class Table
{
   //whatever other properties/methods

   //keep it internal to hide the implementation from the user
   internal Table(StreamReader reader)
   {
      //do what you need to do here
   }
}
```